Would it be possible to build the standard model in terms of Joos-Weinberg spinors?
The Joos-Weinberg equation describes spinors of arbitrary spin. Could we replace all of the existing matter fields (scalar, fermionic, gauge, Rarita Schwinger, etc.) with JW spinors and still end up with a theory which describes reality?

What about interactions?

Do you appreciate  the group structure of the SM summarizes little beyond its interaction structure? Free fields have an enormous symmetry...

What I gather from that is that the different types of fields are needed in order to preserve the necessary symmetries?
